# laravel phpunit Unknown database ':memory:

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

This error is bugging me. my laravel version is 5.6
I don't think I have made any changes to my phpunit.xml file except these

```
<php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>            
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
        <env name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>

    </php>
```

I'm writing test like this:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;

class DemoTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    public function test_it_is_nothing()
    {
        $this->get('/volunteers')->assertStatus('200');
    }
}
```

I have also referenced to this post [Laravel multiple databases PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44392039/laravel-multiple-databases-phpunit) but not helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Please make sure following things:-

- make sure you have sqlite db installed
- clear your config `php artisan config:clear`
- also make sure your phpunit.xml exist on your project root directory
- check if your have DB_DRIVER env in your phpunit.xml please remove it
- when running test try to point your config to phpunit.xml `vendor/bin/phpunit --config PATH_TO_YOUR_PHPUNIT_XML_FILE`
- try to update your phpunit version

If none of above work please try adding another db config to your config/database.php

```
'sqlite_testing' => [
    'driver'   => 'sqlite',
    'database' => ':memory:',
    'prefix'   => '',
]
```

then your phpunit.xml would look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit>
    ...
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
        <env name="DB_DEFAULT" value="sqlite_testing" />
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: I have done all those things.. i have unit version 7.5.6.

Comment: Have you updated phpunit version ? Can you please share your phpunit.xml file.

Comment: I updated the answer please have a look that might fix your problem.

Comment: that didnt work.. i did artisan clear as well but instead of using the sqlite its using mysql.. and clearing out my tables

Comment: maybe sqlite is the problem ... I have unzipped `sqlite3.def sqlite3.dll sqlite3.exe` in `C:\sqlite` and set the environment variable.. but sqlite3 on bash is not running it

Comment: i fixed that problem but stuck with  `Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'fgp_test.sessions' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `sessions` where `id` = XTDuo816miXOnmnCHTdXfrZaYouLGrX1IAikZAZP `

Comment: Are you using `use DatabaseMigrations` trait ?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that I was having another connection for the model being tested.
e.g:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Salesperson extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $connection = 'mysql_dynamic_db';

    /**
    * The attributes that are mass assignable.
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'f_name',
        'cnic',
        'address',
        'mobile',
        'email',
        'salary',
        'comm_percent',
    ];
}
```

So for the time when I run tests, I just comment the following line:

```
protected $connection = 'mysql_dynamic_db';
```

and the above error that says *unknown database :memory:* is gone. Now all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

First, check if the line extension=pdo_sqlite is not commented in your php.ini.

change it

```
;extension=pdo_sqlite
```

to

```
extension=pdo_sqlite
```

And go to your config/database.php file and change the sqlite database like the example below

```
'connections' => [
  'sqlite' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlite',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE',database_path('database.sqlite')),
    'prefix' => '',
    'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
  ],
  ....
];
```

to

```
'connections' => [
  'sqlite' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlite',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'database' => ':memory:',
    'prefix' => '',
    'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
  ],
];
```

You can also change the database, but use one for testing, **don't use your production.**

You can simply change the name :memory: to the name of the database you are using like this

this

```
<env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
```

to

```
<env name="DB_DATABASE" value="name_database"/>
```

Don't forget to change the DB_CONNECTION if necessary.